# SQL Server subquery syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I run the query :

```
select count(*) from 
(select idCover from x90..dimCover group by idCover having count(*) > 1)
```

I get the error :

```
Server: Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Line 2: Incorrect syntax near ')'
```

How do I formulate this query correctly?

I'm on SQL Server 2000

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Add an alias after your last bracket.

```
select count(*) from 
(select idCover from x90..dimCover group by idCover having count(*) > 1) a
```

Answer (score 16):

```
SELECT COUNT (*) FROM
 ( SELECT IdCover FROM x90..dimCover group by idCover having count(*) > 1) AS a
```

(note the alias at the end)