# SQL Server Syntax for update via a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I formulate this query

```
update forge..dimInteg2
   set duplicates = 
      (select count(*) from (select idCover 
                                 from x90..dimCover
                                 group by idCover
                                 having count(*) > 1)) 
where dimTable = 'dimCover'
```

to avoid this error

```
Line 6: Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

Similar to [[SQL Server subquery syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102673/sql-server-syntax-question][1])
but I can't seem to get the alias trick to work.

I am on SQL Server 2000

Comment: Can you please use different subject lines? A subject line isn't meant to simply categorize your question, it's meant to be a brief characterization of it. For instance, "SQL Server UPDATE: How to Use Alias"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you missing a bracket?

```
update forge..dimInteg2
set duplicates = 
  (select count(*) from (select idCover 
                             from x90..dimCover
                             group by idCover
                             having count(*) > 1) ) --HERE
where dimTable = 'dimCover'
```

Then the alias solution should work.

Comment: woops - that was a typo, I put the bracket in and got a slightly different error, I've change the question above

Answer (score 0):

Try to add field dimTable to second select statement:

```
update forge..dimInteg2
   set duplicates = 
      (select count(*) from (select idCover --, dimTable HERE
                                 from x90..dimCover
                                 group by idCover
                                 having count(*) > 1) 
where dimTable = 'dimCover'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to name the derived table.

update forge..dimInteg2
   set duplicates = 
      (select count(dimCover.idCover) from (select idCover 
                                 from x90..dimCover
                                 group by idCover
                                 having count(*) > 1) dimCover) 
where dimTable = 'dimCover'