# SQL Subquery Syntax Error Near ')' -- Not missing alias

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, subquery, ssrs-2000

I have a similar problem to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102673/sql-server-subquery-syntax), but the solution in that case was to add an alias to the subquery. In my case, each of my subqueries has an alias, but I'm getting the message `Incorrect syntax near ')'` at the end of each of my subqueries.

I'm writing the query in 2008 R2 but targeting SSRS 2000

My entire query is fairly long, but here's a shortened pseudo-code version:

```
SELECT  A
       ,B
       ,C
       ,D
       ,E

FROM
     (
       SELECT A as 'A', B as 'B', id
       FROM table t
       WHERE A = 'some value'
       GROUP BY A, B
     ) AS sub1

LEFT JOIN 
     (
       SELECT C as 'C', D as 'D', id
       FROM 
            (
               SELECT id
               FROM nutherTable
               WHERE id IN
               (
                   SELECT DISTINCT id
                   FROM sub1
               )
            )
       WHERE D like '%param%'
     ) AS sub2

    ON sub2.id = sub1.id

LEFT JOIN
     (
       SELECT E as 'E', id
       FROM finalTable
       WHERE E IS NOT NULL
     ) AS sub3

     ON sub3.id = sub2.id
```

You'll notice that in the first `LEFT JOIN`, the join uses a subquery, and the `FROM` and `WHERE` clauses within that subquery also use subqueries. In my actual query, both `LEFT JOINs` have this same structure. One of the things I don't understand is that the nested subqueries don't require an alias. If I try to use an alias with the nested clauses, I get an error. So it's only having trouble with the outer queries in the `LEFT JOINs`.

I've read in other posts that subqueries can only return results for a single field, but I've seen many example where multiple fields are returned from a subquery, so I don't think that's the problem here. Or if that's going to be a problem, the error will be different. Everything I've read attributes this problem to lacking an alias for the subquery, and I get the same results with or without an alias (no alias at all, as well as using `AS` and not using `AS`).

Comment: Are you sure you aren't missing an alias before `WHERE D like '%param%' `?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a table alias for every subquery you're using as a result set:

```
LEFT JOIN 
     (
       SELECT C as 'C', D as 'D', id
       FROM 
            (
               SELECT id
               FROM nutherTable
               WHERE id IN
               (
                   SELECT DISTINCT id
                   FROM sub1
               )
            ) SomeTableName -- HERE IS THE PROBLEM
       WHERE D like '%param%'
     ) AS sub2
```

Comment: Thanks, @Yuck. That fixed the error. Now I'm getting a different error on my first subquery. `Invalid object name 'sub1'`. I've tried renaming a couple times. Not sure what else to try off the top of my head.